# What about generalizing grammars?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, formal-grammar

Say we came up with a finite grammar (specifies a finite number of strings) given a set of input strings.  How then do we *generalize* the grammar so that it works for larger input strings and also fills in the gaps of strings we didn't specify, correctly?

I have an idea. Say inputs that looked like:

'a' 
'aa'
'aaaa'
'aaaaa'

Then a possible given grammar is $G \to a + a(a + a(a +a(a + a))))$.  Then I think since $|s|$ the length of the input string $|s|$ follows some pattern, if we come up with a good guess for that then we can build our grammar based on it.

What would you guys do?  I think also we need an output grammar that in addition represents interesting functions to try to generalize grammar from.

Comment: I think that you will have to include some negative examples, as the grammar of the full language would be the simplest matching. Also, there is a huge problem that could be stated as: how would you generalize $aa, aaaa, aaaaaa, aaaaaaaa$, would $aaa$ be in the language? Finally, any precise approach seems computationally infeasible. Why don't you take a look at [PCFGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_context-free_grammar)?

Comment: @dtldarek First, we use a small set of strings.  Second, you're right, there's no **correct** interpretation, since how do you define what's correct, it's pretty arbitrary and can even change within our human contexts.  Thus, we need to find a "homomorphism" between input strings and output strings, where the output provides the context.  For example we'd want $a \to 1, aa \to 2, \dots$ if we're in the process of defining a string length function.

Comment: I think this question ("given some examples, how can you determine what the rule may be?") is essentially what the entire field of machine learning tries to answer. I don't know how to give a better answer than "I suggest reading a machine learning textbook".

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_of_regular_languages